# How do I add csrf_meta_tags to my .coffee.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csrf, erb

I have a .coffeescript.erb file in which I would like to get CSRF meta-tag information in Rails 3.1. The file is called bookmarklet.coffee.erb and it is in my assets/javascript folder. This is the code I am using:

```
csrfMeta = <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

When I access assets/bookmarklet.js, I see this in my server log

```
Error compiling asset bookmarklet.js:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `csrf_meta_tags' for #<#<Class:0x007f83d2efc3a8>:0x007f83d4043080>
```

How can I get the CSRF meta tags into my javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the CSRF tags to show up by moving the file into my views/parser folder, and renaming it as bookmarklet.js.coffee. Instead of using csrf_meta_tags, I used the helper form_tag which automatically includes the CSRF tags.